# how i can write a professional documentaion for big network

Tags: networking, cisco, documentation, document-management, network-design

I design a big network and i want to document my design in documentation . all thing swhitch, router, server and ip address ........ 
and i want to simulate it and draw it 
if anyone have a sample of documentaion to complex network system please provide me 
and please if you can Proposed to me some program to use it .

Comment: Whatever software you end up using I'd try using correct spelling and grammar :)

Comment: Some great thoughts on the topic of documentation (not diagramming) : http://serverfault.com/questions/25404/documentation-as-a-manual-vs-documentation-as-a-checklist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For programs, both Visio and Dia are fine candidates. But while you are at it, read also [Documentation Writing for System Administrators](http://www.sage.org/pubs/11_documenting/) (It is behind a paywall though).

Comment: It's true that it's behind a paywall, but SAGE is a very worthwhile thing to join, for a sysadmin.  I'm not currently a member, but when I lived in the US, I was, and thought it well worthwhile.

Comment: I live in Greece and have been a member of USENIX and SAGE since 1997. LOPSA (I think) is more US oriented.

Comment: I felt while I lived there, which was in the '90s, that SAGE was quite US-oriented.  I'm very pleased to hear that it's expanded its mindset, and will have to consider signing up again.  Thanks, adamo!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a Mac, consider Omnigraffle for diagrams.

http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/

Answer (score 2):

Or if you'd prefer to use free software to do your documentation, try [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia); it has both Linux and Windows versions.

Comment: Dia falls flat when you start to get into very involved network diagrams. mostly due to limitations of the QT framework (IIRC QT not supporting vector graphics)

Comment: Doubtless true, but it's the best free software I can find.  If you have a free alternative that does what you want, do feel free to post it!

Comment: wish i did, but I've pretty much given up and use visio. All the major vendors have stencils, and it just works right, although visio '10 changes enough things just slightly to start to be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Microsoft Visio, there are plenty of tutorials out there to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.gliffy.com I've used this on big projects because it allows for collaborative work on the diagram.

Even if you dont have a team working on the drawing this is a really cool alternative to M$ Vi$io

Answer (score 1):

The site is somewhat tongue-in-cheek, but you can check out "Rate My Network Diagram" (http://www.ratemynetworkdiagram.com/index2.php) for many examples of all sorts of different networks.